# Deutsches Wort für “check”

Tags: translation

Für "check" im Sinne von "to validate that something works", denke ich, dass das Wort "prüfen" passt. Aber in folgenden Fällen:

> - I need to check what that word means.
> - Check to see if it works.
> - Check if someone called you.

glaube ich, dass das Wort "check" durch "prüfen" nicht übersetzt werden kann.

Comment: Die Begründung, warum *prüfen* nict funktionieren soll, ist ein bisschen dünn. Was spricht denn dagegen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not simply a single word for "check".

> Check if someone called you.

Can be expressed, depending on situation, circumstances, register of speech, environment, participants in the conversation, mood of the person speaking and so on for exammple by

> Kuck mal, ob dich jemand angerufen hat.
>
> Kuck mal nach, ob dich wer angerufen hat.
>
> Überprüfen Sie bitte, ob jemand Sie angerufen hat.
>
> Prüfen Sie einmal, ob Sie jemand angerufen hat.
>
> Schauen Sie mal nach, ob jemand Sie angerufen hat.
>
> Check mal ob wer angerufen hat.
>
> Mach mal'n Check, ob jemand angerufen hat.
>
> Hat da wer angerufen? Kannt du das mal abchecken?
>
> Hat da jetzt wer angerufen? Ich check's grad nicht. Check' doch mal.
>
> Kontrolliere doch  mal, ob nicht jemand dich angerufen hat.
>
> Sieh mal, ob dich jemand angerufen hat.
>
> Sieh mal nach, ob jemand dich angerufen hat.
>
> Prüf mal, ob wer angerufen hat.
>
> Der Inspektor unterzog den Telefonapparat einer eingehenden Prüfung, um festzustellen, ob Meier vor seinem Tode noch einen Anruf bekommen hatte.

... and many others.

Note: all variants wich "check" are between ugly and adolescent. Some people talk that way in informal situations indeed, but you would not find this in writing.

Fun fact: the sentences *Ich check's grad nicht. Check doch mal!* showcase that *checken* has two meanings in German: a) to understand b) to verify.

Comment: Bei der anderen Antwort hat der OP darum gebeten, auf Deutsch zu schreiben.

Comment: @CarsteS  Herrje. Ich vergesse immer, welches jetzt Deutsch und welches Englisch war...  aber ich habe ja genug deutsches Spielmaterial dagelassen.

Answer (score 5):

GER: Nicht nur "prüfen", sondern auch "überprüfen, nachprüfen". Deine Beispiele könnten alle mit diesen Wörtern übersetzt werden. Die Sätze wären korrekt, jedoch würde man bevorzugt andere Worte benutzen, wie z.B. "nachschauen".

ENG: I think it's not purely "prüfen", but also "überprüfen", "nachprüfen". You're examples could all be translated with those words, and the sentences would be correct, but in those situation are often replaced by other words.

> - Ich muss überprüfen (im Sinne von nachschauen/nachschlagen) was dieses Wort bedeutet.
> - Überprüfe (im Sinne von nachschauen/validieren), ob es funktioniert.
> - Überprüfe (im Sinne von nachschauen), ob dich jemand angerufen hat. *Alternativ: Prüf bitte nach, ob dich jemand angerufen hat.*

GER: Wie gesagt, diese Ausdrücke werden selten bis gar nicht mehr gebraucht, wären aber rein technisch anwendbar. Hier greift ein Effekt, der in allen Sprachen vorkommt, die Verschiebung von Wortbedeutungen. während ursprünglich die Übersetzung durch prüfen wohl passend war, wurde es mittlerweile durch Ausdrücke wie "nachschauen" ersetzt. Ein anderes Beispiel dafür wäre "Gift" (dt/eng). Das deutsche und englische "Gift" hatten ursprüunglich die gleiche Bedeutung von *geben, to give, die Gabe (speziell im medizinischen Sinn)*. Gift bedeutete ursrpünglich *Gabe, Dosis*.

ENG: As said, those expressions aren't in use that much, but would technically be viable. Note: in all languages, the meaning of words slowly shift, that's why "nachschauen" has replaced "überprüfen" in those cases. Another example would be "Gift". German "Gift" and English "gift" once meant the same, deriving from *geben, to give, die Gabe*. "Gift" once meant "Dosis" or "Gabe".
In your examples, "check" could be replaced with "look" or "look up", same applies in German.

EDIT: it doesn't work if "check" is used for "check an item on the list" -> "abhaken"

Comment: Sorry, ich arbeite, lese und kommuniziere zurzeit hauptsächlich im englischen, da passiert das irgendwie automatisch. Soll ich's übersetzen?

Comment: @miep Ja, bitte.

Comment: @sermonionx here you go

Comment: So is it überprüfen or nachschauen? What would sound more common for german natives?

Comment: Kontrollieren?  I quite often see Germans using "control" for "kontrollieren", when I think "check" would be better.  (This is mostly in BW if that makes a difference.)

Comment: Kontrollieren hat zwei Bedeutungen: etwas überprüfen *oder* etwas steuern. daher passt die Übersetzung in diesem Falle, umgekehrt ist kontrollieren nicht immer "check"    @sermonionx in diesen Fällen definitiv nachschauen. Wie gesagt, technisch gesehen ist "überprüfen" *auch* korrekt, "nachschauen" ist aber weitaus gängiger.

Comment: Ich stimme nicht zu, dass andere Worte als 'prüfen' bevorzugt werden oder zu bevorzugen sind. In manchen Milieus mag es eine Verschiebung gegeben haben, aber ganz sicher nicht in allen. Insbesondere ist "nachschauen" sehr viel unverbindlicher als "prüfen". Ich stelle mich auf die Waage, um mein Gewicht zu überprüfen (kontrollieren), sicher nicht um es bloß nachzuschauen. Die Frische von Obst, Fleisch, Fisch usw. prüft man auch taktil und mit dem Geruchssinn, nicht nur schauend.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt verschiedene Möglichkeiten "to check" im Deutschen auszudrücken:

> - [prüfen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pruefen)
> - [überprüfen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueberpruefen)
> - [kontrollieren](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kontrollieren)

Hierbei liegt der Fokus mehr auf der Kontrolle von etwas. Prüfen hat eine etwas schwächere Wirkung als die anderen beiden Worte aber generell gehst du davon aus, dass etwas fehlerhaft sein könnte.

Als Fachbegriff kannst du

> - [etwas verifizieren](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verifizieren)

nehmen...

Desweiteren ginge auch:

> - [nachsehen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachsehen)

Wobei dies mehr in die Richtung [etwas nachschlagen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachschlagen) oder etwas nachlesen geht.